# Youtube-dl Question: How can I batch download files (while assigning different titles to output files)?

Tags: youtube-dl

I have a `.txt` file with a list of `.m3u8` links. I want to batch download all these links (videos) without having to manually enter them one by one.

The problem I'm having is this: `youtube-dl` is giving the output files the SAME NAME, and this is stopping me from batch downloading files, because after the first file is downloaded, I get the error message (for the following files) that `this file already exists.`

So because the same name is being applied to any download, I'm not able to download more than one file at a time.

Can someone please help with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use `-o` option:

```
youtube-dl -a batch_file \
 -o "%(title)s by %(uploader)s on %(upload_date)s in %(playlist)s.%(ext)s"
```

> -o, --output TEMPLATE
>
> Output filename template, see the "Output Template" for all the info

There are a lot of patterns you can use differentiate files from each other.

```
id (string): Video identifier
display_id (string): An alternative identifier for the video
timestamp (numeric): UNIX timestamp of the moment the video became available
duration (numeric): Length of the video in seconds
view_count (numeric): How many users have watched the video on the platform
like_count (numeric): Number of positive ratings of the video
...
```

https://www.mankier.com/1/youtube-dl#Output_Template

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Ravexina! I'm really grateful. Sorry for responding late - I was testing out different possibilities you suggested, but still having trouble, because when I run the following command, then the files don't render correctly:

youtube-dl -a batch-file.txt -o "%(title)s by %(url)s"

I've also tried other possibilities, but the file doesn't download completely & VLC player shows me errors when playing it (even though youtube-dl tells me that files were 100% downloaded successfully - though the file sizes are much smaller than they're supposed to be).

Comment: %(url)s could be a troubling variable to use within a filename, try something more simple like %(id)s to see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If the filename is not a major concern, especially while testing, I would recommend using the autonumber variable and a simple id:

```
youtube-dl --batch-file batch_file.txt -o "File %(autonumber)s (%(id)s).%(ext)s"
```

As mentioned in the comment above, using a url variable in a filename could be troublesome.